# Грань между пословицей и поговоркой

Tags: фразеология

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти грань между пословицей и поговоркой. Я так понимаю, что пословица - это что-то вроде мудрой народной мысли, выраженной в некоем поучении, например, "без труда не вытянешь и рыбку из пруда". Но при этом открываем сборник русских поговорок и читаем, к примеру: "Вольно всякому на своей земле яму копать" или "     Как назначат в лесу воеводой лису, пера будет много, а птицы нет". И, честно говоря, я не вижу разницы между этими высказываниями и "рыбкой из пруда".
Чем же все-таки пословица отличается от поговорки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пословицы и поговорки имеют общие признаки – народность, краткость, меткость, афористичность, даже рифму.

Пословица

Представляет собой логически законченное выражение, которое предполагает какое-то действие. Состоит, как правило, из двух частей. Пословица обязательно подразумевает некое назидание, поучение или мораль: Готовь телегу зимой, сани летом. Лучше один раз увидеть, чем сто раз услышать.

Поговорка

Это лаконичное народное  выражение, метко характеризующее какое-то явление или закономерность. Поговорка, в отличие от пословицы, не подразумевает действия и не несет в себе назидания или поучения: Два сапога – пара. Нет дыма без огня. Каков поп – таков приход.
http://otvet-plus.ru/proverbo.htm

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Мне кажется, что поговорку можно назвать приговоркой. Поговорки часто встраиваются в речь в качестве  попутной образной оценки излагаемых событий.

Answer (score 1):

**поговорка**. Образное, иносказательное выражение, метко определяющее какое-либо жизненное явление, лаконичное по форме, в отличие от пословицы не заключающее в себе прямого поучительного смысла, с чем часто связана синтаксическая незаконченность. *Вот где собака зарыта. Из молодых, да ранний. Мир не без добрых людей. Не в коня корм. Нет дыма без огня. Ни богу свечка, ни черту кочерга. Ни пава, ни ворона. После дождика в четверг. Пуганая ворона куста боится. Сухая ложка рот дерет.*

Розенталь и др. Словарь лингвистических терминов